# Announcement: I'm retiring

Tags: discussion, moderators, specific-user

I've been thinking about this for some months now, and recently I've made up my mind to retire from moderator duty. It has been an awesome four years, and I see a lot of positive in how the community has developed during that time. So I want to thank the early users who put their faith in me, and also the entire community for their support of the mod team in general.

**Practicalities**

An election will be held in the near future *[Edit 2014-12-10: [right now!](https://math.stackexchange.com/election)]*. (Possibly quite soon; we are in discussion with the Community Team on the best timing.) I will stay on until the election is over, at which time my diamond will be removed and the newly minted moderator(s) will take over.

**Reasons**

I am sure a lot of you will want to know why I am retiring. Just to get it out of the way:

- No, there's been no disagreements in the mod team.
- No, I have no qualms with the direction that the site is going.
- No, I have no trouble working with the Community Team (SE Inc).

If anything it is just that after 4 years, I find that I cannot summon the same level of enthusiasm that I had earlier in my moderator term. In addition, I have become more busy all around and with there being only 24 hours in a day I find myself slowly slowly cutting away my time on Math.SE for other tasks and duties. So while I am not burnt-out per se, I still don't think that I can serve the community in a capacity that meets my own standards.

Another reason is that I have come to understand, after 4 years in service, how much the smooth running of this website depends on *you* the users in general. Due to the big unilateral hammer we carry, moderators have often refrained from the day-to-day maintenance activities (think close/delete votes for example), and deal generally only in the more exceptional problems. This means that I realized that I can still contribute, in some ways and in my own schedule, to the growth of this community, even without my diamond. (So yes, maybe I will earn some of those other moderation badges!)

---

In conclusion, thanks for the ride, and see y'all around.

Comment: On the one hand, I want to downvote, since I don't like good mods retiring. On the other hand: Thanks for the hard work.

Comment: I would like to thank you in particular thank you for your effort related to [tags, correct tagging and tag management](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/92/tagging?userid=1543) and also for your [activity on meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/discussion/topusers).

Comment: @MartinSleziak: I take it as a sign of health of the community when "ordinary users" like you and Rafflesia and others are now providing a lot of meta support and opinions guiding the growth of the site. I have found it wonderful the number of non-moderator initiated things that have happened: the most prominent for me being the tagging (and other special issues) chatrooms.

Comment: See you on the playground, then! Thanks for the hard hard work!

Comment: I'm glad you'll still be around and this isn't a total retirement from the site. You've served the community very well these last years.

Comment: Might as well go out with a [song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QqdFTPyW5L0&start=156)!

Comment: @WillieWong Thanks for your service. I'm a relatively new user here and I really admire the community. It takes a set of dedicated moderators to keep the site running well, and I think you (and the others!) have done a fine job

Comment: Thank you for your contributions to the site, both mathematical and moderatorial.

Comment: The title scared me because I thought you were retiring from the site altogether.

Comment: Disclaimer: Like Daniel Fischer, my upvote is to be taken as a sign of gratitude for your (Willie's) hard work, over four years time, your fairness, and my fond memories of my earliest interactions with you when I was a fledgling newbie at MSE.

Comment: I'll miss you! You've been consistently patient and sweet. Thank you for being moderator here for so long.

Comment: Yay! You have a blog. I just subscribed :O)

Comment: Well, no offence but is this technically the right way to address the users of SE for such a message? There should actually be a news column where all the users get notified about such events (in my opinion).

Comment: @user45195 There is a news column: "Hot Meta Posts" in the sidebar on the main site. This post appeared there for a while after its creation.

Comment: A Moderator's [GOT to know](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_VrFV5r8cs0) his limits (paraphrased from Dirty Harry...)

Comment: @user45195 Something similar was discussed here: [How can we increase user involvement on this meta site?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16440/how-can-we-increase-user-involvement-on-this-meta-site). (That discussion was sparked by another post on meta.)

Comment: This is great news. Now you have time to write up the ultimate blog post on separation of variables in PDEs :) Seriously though, thanks for your effort these past years.

Comment: [So long and thanks for all the fish](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ojydNb3Lrrs).

Comment: I'll miss you as a moderator. But it is good that you are still able to help the community even without your ♦.

Comment: You are really fishing for that great question badge, aren't you? :-) [Sorry for the silly remark. You have been a great moderator and I am really sorry you stop, and this is my way of mourning.]

Comment: @quid: I haven't actually seen the vote total until you mentioned it. (Comment notifications bring me straight here and doesn't show me the "top part" of the screen.) So close! Yet so far! (But JFYI [I already have one](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question).)

Comment: You are there! But it wasn't me. I upvoted long ago.

Comment: Thank you so much for your part in making this a high quality community.