# 2014 Nominations for moderator on Math.SE

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

As suggested on the chat of Mathematics 2014 Moderator Election, I'm opening this thread to give us an opportunity to nominate our choices for moderator.

Please state the your candidate election and set your reason why he/she should be elected.

Maybe we can convince some of them to nominate themselves on [the official election page](https://math.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1).

Comment: I don't really see the point of this thread. All the people nominated here are sufficiently active on the website to 1/ know there's a moderator election 2/ have decided by themselves whether they want to be moderators or not.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi some people might be hesitant to simply nominate themselves.

Comment: I nominate @Did :D

Comment: @NajibIdrissi this would be unfortunate, yet  I do not believe there to be a positive corelation between "hesitates to self-nominate" and "hesitates to moderate."

Comment: Users often don't know each other's capabilities. A user with a good rep from every sense online, may not be good at moderation, or may not have the free time required to spend on the site.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Knowing that many people wants (or don't) you to be a moderator might be useful information to consider when your deciding if you should run to be a moderator.

Comment: I am beginning to worry that some people are taking the title of this post to mean that there are supposed to 2,014 nominations for moderator!

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I am a moderator on one of the SE sites. I certainly hesitated quite a bit before taking the plunge and accepting a nomination; it's a big responsibility. But it doesn't follow that I have been hesitant *as* a moderator.

Comment: @Gerry: 2014 nomination for mod, 2014 posts! One user inclined to decline, 2013 nomination for mod! (The rest of the song is left as an exercise for the reader.)

Comment: @Asaf, $\aleph_0$ bottles of beer on the wall, $\aleph_0$ bottles of beer! If one of those bottles should happen to fall, $\aleph_0$ bottles of beer on the wall!

Comment: @Gerry: After repeating this song $\omega_1$ times I suddenly noticed that there are no more bottles of beer on the wall. :(

Answer (score 55):

> [Accepted](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/5#post-1067491)

I nominate [Daniel Fischer](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/83702/daniel-fischer).

He is very active, above conflicts, and is quite patient in explaining how things are with the newbies.  I have every confidence, based on what I have seen, that Daniel will be an excellent moderator.

Comment: I nominated myself but I strongly agree about Daniel Fischer's skills.

Comment: I couldn't agree more with you Ron G. Please accept this nomination Daniel sensei.

Comment: 'quite patient in explaining how things are with the newbies' .. @DanielFischer san is good and patient with 'explaining' in general imho ! :-)

Comment: Fischer & Fischer is a good combination!

Comment: I realize in writing this I was a bit presumptuous in stating that Daniel "will" make a good moderator.  He needs to accept the nomination and be elected first.

Answer (score 38):

> The user has **declined**.

I nominate [Martin Sleziak](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/8297/martin-sleziak).

He is very active, not only but also  on meta, and takes upon himself various somewhat thankless tasks, like retagging and editing numerous  questions (just note 6600+ edits *and* 1400+  *on meta*). So, while he also  has a very respectable point count of 27k, this understates his involvement by a lot.

He seems always patient and friendly, and is typically not in the middle of the many fights we see, but rather above them, as a voice of reason and compromise.

There are very different views how this site should be organized,  so I feel it is important to vote for a moderator that is actually moderate in his views and moderating in his actions.

Please, Martin, accept this nomination.

---

M.S.: Let me answer here, instead of in a comment. (This way my response will have better visibility and it is probably too long for a comment.)

First of, thanks to quid for the suggestion and also to the users who voted on this post. I do appreciate your kind words, although I am not sure they are fully deserved.

The main reason why I have to decline is that I have other duties. (Unfortunately, there also is the real world.) And in the following year the amount of my duties is probably going to be more time consuming. (You might have noticed that I already answer questions on main much less that I used to. And my retags and participation on meta are basically *"out of habit"* when I come here to procrastinate.) If I were to become a moderator, I would have to spend more time on MSE and quite regularly. I simply cannot take a commitment like this at my current situation.

This in no way means that I intent to stop contributing to the site. (And I also hope to use the site for my own advantage to learn the new things.) 
The point I want to make was very well explained by Willie Wong. [In this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17372/announcement-im-retiring) he stresses the importance of *the day-to-day maintenance activities* and he goes on to say: *This means that I realized that I can still contribute, in some ways and in my own schedule, to the growth of this community, even without my diamond.* I certainly agree with what he writes. And it is possible that I can be much more useful to the site as a regular user than I would be as a mod.

I am also not entirely sure whether I would be suitable as a mod. Being a mod also requires people skills. You write that I am *typically not in the middle of the many fights*. This is mainly because in the past I have left some discussions on meta with a feel of bitterness. So now I do my best to steer away from the discussions which are prone to be controversial or personal. As a mod I probably should not ignore some discussions on meta - simply because of the reasons that as a mod I should listen to the "voice of the community".

For a future reference, let me say that I understand the importance of having good moderators. In the future, when moderator elections come again, I will think about it and decide for myself. (When Willie Wong mentioned in his post that elections are coming, I thought about this and decided not to run for the reasons explained above.) There is no need to make a post like this in the future - if I am still active on the site and elections come, I will always consider to which extent I would be useful to the community as a mod and whether I would be able to honor such a commitment. (I am not sure whether I will really run for a mod at some point, but I spent some time thinking about it this time and I will do so also in the future.)

So, once again, thanks for your suggestion. I am satisfied with my role on the site at the moment. (And I will be glad if I find time and energy to improve my involment in the site.) But I will have to decline.

Comment: quid: Have you considered running as a moderator yourself? (But I know that you are already mod on another site and you are pretty active at MO, so that is probably already quite time consuming.) This comment might be considered somewhat off-topic in this thread. If you prefer, you can [answer in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18969445#18969445) instead. And if you tell me there (or here) that you prefer this comment to be deleted, I will do so.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Just go ahead and nominate quid. Think of it as quid pro quo.

Comment: @ArthurFischer The post with the nomination would be useless if quid says right away that he won't run. That's why decided to ping him about that first.

Comment: @MartinSleziak It's a pity. Your well-reasoned decline strengthens my belief that you would be a good moderator.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks for the detailed reply. This is a pity. I will reply to the rest elswhere and later.

Answer (score 8):

I suggest the user [hardmath](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/users/3111/hardmath).

He/she is very active in main as well as meta, has relevant badges and in my opinion his/her interactions in meta is reflects his/her maturity and thus shows the potential to be a good moderator.

Answer (score 7):

> declined

I'd like to nominate [Jonas Meyer](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1424/jonas-meyer)

According to the [Citizenship score query](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/256802/) mentioned in [Behaviour's answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17671/how-much-experience-should-a-potential-moderator-have#17674) he is one of the few users having considerably high citizenship score ($37$) as well as good activity on meta.

Answer (score 5):

> The user has declined.

I suggest

- Asaf Karagila

  Because he is always present, is patient, and have been really helpful during the few months I'm being a member.

Comment: I can't say that the lucrative diamond powers don't have their allure. But I don't think that I was cut to be a moderator on this site, and I have no intention to be one. I prefer to remain active as I am at this moment, and to contribute my efforts by flagging, reviewing and voting to close and delete. But thanks for the vote of confidence!

Answer (score 5):

Nomination of [Pedro Tamaroff](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/23350/pedro-tamaroff)

I nominate myself. [Here you can find the reasons](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/5#post-1058424).

Comment: Have you posted this in order to convince yourself to nominate yourself  on the [official election page](http://math.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1)?

Comment: @Behaviour Yes. I thought this was a pre-warm up for the warm up (official nominations) which precedes the work out (voting) that will lead to the post work out (moderators being elected).

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Someone's been watching to much My wife and the Kids.

Comment: You guys are funny.

Answer (score 5):

> **Nomination of** [**Anastasiya-Romanova**](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/133248/anastasiya-romanova)

So far the nomination page reveals that female users are less likely to nominate theirselves or to be nominated by the other users, so I decide to take this opportunity to nominate myself as a moderator (My official nomination can be seen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/5#post-1059198)). Please, do not see this as a gender issue. I am not a feminist and I consider being a female as my advantage since, if I am not mistaken, Mathematics StackExchange has never had a female moderator although I am still very young but age does not determine someone's maturity. In addition, if I am elected as a moderator and one day I quarrel with a user here, I think this user will behave nice (at least no dirty words will be spoken out) to me knowing that I am a young female moderator. I am aware that sometime I am *emotionally unstable* (No, I am not having mental illness, just a common thing as a teenager) and behave so silly, but I promise I will be on my best behaviour if I am elected as a moderator.

I have been around here since 9 months ago, I have learned and know how the system here works. Although my contribution on Math SE is very small compared to the prominent users here, considering my age and the little time I've been here, I think it is not negligible. I have enough experience because I have participated in many similar sites like Math SE, i.e.

- [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Anastasiya-Romanova)
- [Brilliant.org](https://brilliant.org/profile/valentina-dsnv7v/)
- [Integrals and Series](http://integralsandseries.prophpbb.com/member145.html)
- [AoPS](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&u=229417)

I am also rather well-known there, so if I am elected as a moderator I hope people there especially young men/ women are also interested in joining in our community and giving positive contributions to this site after knowing that an ordinary young girl like me can be a moderator here. I also always promote and advertise this site while contributing and participating in other sites, for examples I create topic [Mathematics StackExchange on Quora](http://qr.ae/qyeJt) and I always cites the link of this site for almost every questions and answers I have posted. All of these has been and will be a good promotion for this site.

I have learned so much from this site and I think it is about time for me to give back. While Mr. Martin Sleziak has said that I can still contribute to the growth of this community, in some ways and in my own schedule, even without my diamond, serving as a moderator will give me bigger chances to improve my contributions than as an ordinary user. I have good enough mathematics skills, I like to get along with the users here, and most importantly, I have a lot of time to serve this site.

I have no more to say and I hope I am not making any immodest statements, excessively praising myself, nor also showing narcissism on my part. Thank you and may God bless Mathematics StackExchange.

Comment: `"I am aware that sometime I am emotionally unstable (No, I am not having mental illness, just a common thing as a teenager) and behave so silly, but I promise I will be on my best behaviour if I am elected as a moderator."`
If you only explain me this, i'll consider voting for you!

Comment: Anna, are you serious running for moderator in this election? Anyway, you look cute with the outfit in your new ava. :-)

Comment: @chouaib I have to admit that sometimes I can be so upset when someone does serial/ anonymous downvotes to my posts (without explanation or stating where is the wrong part) or I have an argument with someone in chat room but I assure you I can perfectly handle this situation because this is only common things.

Comment: @Venus As Sawarnik said in his comment, my answer is YUP! I've never been more serious in all my life than this time. Thanks for your praise, I change my ava only for this election so that I look more mature than the silly previous one. (͡• ͜ʖ ͡•)

Comment: you say that you are not a feminist. what do you mean by that? what does a person being a feminist mean?

Comment: @abel makes an excellent point. Furthermore, I don't understand why feminism is even broached as a topic in the OP moderator nomination... um, self-nomination.

Comment: @abel [Let me Google that for you](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=feminist#) $\ddot\smile$

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova秀 He was not asking for a definition of feminist. He's asking what *you* mean by it, and Ellie is asking why you brought it up - both, I think, good questions.

Comment: @MikeMiller May I know why do you always comment below my nomination speech, either the unofficial or the official one?

Comment: Because there remained parts of your nomination I would like clarified.

Comment: Hope you'll become a new moderator. It's a long time to not seeing women to become moderator here. Here, I think you're the only women here, so I think it's good to choose you as new moderator for the future. Beside that, I want to learn more about how to integrating many functions, because Integration is very challenging to me.

Comment: @akusaja Terima kasih atas dukungannya kakak (>‿◠)✌

Comment: yo, sama2...moga2 pengetahuan saya ttg kalkulus bs tambah nantinya dengan kamu sbg moderator. :)

Answer (score 2):

> The user said they would **decline** a nomination.

My suggestions

- André Nicolas

Because they are always present, are patient, and have been really helpful during the few months I was a member.

Comment: What!? I thought everyone loves Andre. This is so mean. T_T

Comment: @Venus Do you consider mod election a popularity contest?

Comment: I am temperamentally unsuited to be a moderator. It would be disturbing to be considered moderate.

Comment: @Behaviour No, I don't. Do you think so? My point is if she/ he doesn't want Andre to be a moderator, she/ he can simply ignore this answer instead of downvoting it. IMHO, it's really unacceptable & I consider this kind of behaviour as a psychological abuse for the candidates.

Comment: @Venus One might think a user is a good mod candidate. One might think a user is a bad mod candidate. Or one might not have any opinion at all, for lack of knowledge maybe. These translate into votes as +1, -1, 0 (no vote). Mixing the latter two categories together would be throwing some information out.

Comment: @André: If you decline this suggestion, please add a notice on the top.

Comment: Some want to be lieutenant and some prefer sergeant major. André's comment makes sense to me. I expect he may or may not send the request to add notice to the paper shufflers, he being a top soldier not having those duties in his job description.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I don't see why the users mentioned here should bother editing the posts with rejection notice. One declines these unofficial "pre-nominations"  simply by not nominating oneself. There's no need for a rejection speech or even any acknowledgment of the post.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: It seems to be not a nomination, but a suggestion. My thanks go to Aaron Maroja, but if nominated I will decline.

Comment: @Andre: Yes, and when you receive an invitation to a wedding, you can confirm, decline or just ignore it.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: A wedding is another matter. As long as it is not mine, I am willing to attend, and, if properly lubricated, even dance the hora.

Comment: Disturbing to be a "moderator," but maybe open to being a "radicalator"? :)

Comment: @Behaviour it is not necessary but I for one find it convenient to get an overview. The user performing it themselves minimizes risk of misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2):

> The user has **declined**.

[Brian M Scott](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/users/12042/brian-m-scott)

Apart from being a great mathematician, he cares a lot for the community.

As can be seen for example from his good contributions to the list of questions to the candidates [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17615/36639), [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17617/36639), and [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17616/36639), he nicely represents and defends the original traditions and standards of the community, which made Math SE a good place with a nice academic atmosphere for people who want to help each other learning and doing mathematics together.

---

BMS: I’ll follow Martin’s lead by commenting here. I appreciate the nomination (to say nothing of the undeserved compliment on my mathematical skill!), but I’ve no desire to be a moderator. I’ve successfully held a number of positions elsewhere that required similar skills and willingness to subordinate one’s own views to a large extent to prevailing community standards, and I think that I could do a decent job, but that same experience has taught me that I wouldn’t enjoy it. I’ll stick to answering questions: that’s both my forte and something that I greatly enjoy.

There are other reasons for me to decline as well. It’s no secret that I’ve a view of what MSE should be that is not universally shared. (We all do, of course, but mine is further from the middle ground than most.) I fear that this has made me something of a polarizing figure, and as such a poor choice on general principles. Moreover, while I dislike getting involved in the pie fights, I want to be able to speak up for that view at will; as a moderator I’d not feel free to do so.

Finally, I had to walk away from MSE a year ago, and I can’t promise that I won’t need to walk away again at some point.

Answer (score 1):

> The user **declined.**

I nominate [MJD](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/users/25554/mjd).

He seems always patient and friendly, and is typically not in the middle of the many fights we see, but rather above them, as a voice of reason and compromise. I copied a part of quid's post verbatim. If you don't like that quid tell me and I'll make it in my own words. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your kind words,  but I don't think I would be a good choice.

Answer (score -2):

> **[declined](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18978671#18978671)**

It doesn't seem like anyone has nominated [the user soon to be formerly known](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/17364/revisions) as Behaviour. They're quite active on meta and seem quite willing to be firm, but not rude, in defense of the quality standards of the community. They also have quite an idea of what qualities would be good in a moderator, as evidenced by their considerable commenting on the elections page. I think they would, in general, be a strong positive presence as a moderator*.

(And of course, if they've previously stated that they don't want to be a moderator, I can't find it since they keep changing their name)

*Not that they aren't already.

Comment: 117490 has previously [made it clear](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18968622#18968622) that they are not interested in becoming a moderator.

Comment: He mentioned it at least twice in chat, see [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/19294?m=18968622#18968622) and [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18978819#18978819). But I think it is better to wait until the user himself comments to it, so we can say whether he has officially declined. (Or - this is still a possibility - that after so many users asking him to run, he changed his mind.)

Comment: @Behaviour It's Time to change your name to [*Not running for a mod, stop asking*](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18978671#18978671)

Comment: @MikeMiller 117490? I'm 147263.

Answer (score -2):

I nominate [mrf](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/19440/mrf).

He has been a member for 3 years and seems to have a nice activity balance between the main and meta sites. Skimming his posting history, I only found well-received questions, answers and comments. His involvement in the discussions concerning this election makes me think, and hope, that he has an interest and commitment to help making math.SE a great place.

Answer (score -17):

I nominate [lab bhattacharjee](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/33337/lab-bhattacharjee) to be a moderator. For the time I have been on Math.SE I can say that he has always been always present, patient, and really helpful. I think he will be a great moderator.