# Is the election all my fault?

Tags: discussion, election

I was wondering is it all my fault?

Last May (just to get the caucus badge )  I asked " [When is the next Moderator Election?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13832/when-is-the-next-moderator-election) "

and now all nonsence of  [Low quality of election nominees](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/17639/low-quality-of-election-nominees) is upon us.

Was wondering should I nominate  myself , or is it better to wait another year? (till i understand more on the subjects i am active in)

sorry all

also is there no system thata you can ask other to nominate themselves (just to say you think they are good moderators and would support them)

Comment: No, it's not your fault.  One event that prompted the election was [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/17372/23353).  (I don't know if that's the *only* prompt or not, though.)

Comment: I am completely missing even the most remote connection between a minor 7 month old post and a current election. Moreover, the notion of some old post progenitor fault in these seemingly disjoint occurrences is unfathomable to me. I wonder if maybe I recently lost my funny bone or something.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, it is not your fault.

If you want to encourage some user to nominate themselves, see  [2014 Nominations for moderator on Math.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/17598/).

As for whether or not you should nominate yourself... that's only your decision, but I'd suggest waiting until you get better at using the site (e.g., not overlooking the aforementioned election-related thread that is currently on the front page). I would also expect moderator candidates to use uppercase letters where appropriate, and write in structured sentences.